# In Java elegant way to get each section of path up to Root

Tags: java

Is there a more elegant way to get each section of path up to Root
e.g given

```
E:\AllMusic\The Shadows\The Very Best of The Shadows
```

I want to get

```
E:\AllMusic\The Shadows\The Very Best of The Shadows
E:\AllMusic\The Shadows
E:\AllMusic
E:\
```

I have done it with code below (I am just printing out path but in real code need to do something with these paths), but it seems very convoluted. I do want to do this properly, and note it has to work with Windows/Unix etc so I dont want to be doing clever hacks with Strings. Im using Java 8.

```
System.out.println(folder);
while(folder.getNameCount()>1)
{
    if(folder.getRoot()!=null)
    {
        folder = folder.getRoot().resolve(folder.subpath(0, folder.getNameCount() - 1));
    }
    System.out.println(folder);
}
if(folder.getRoot()!=null)
{
    System.out.println(folder.getRoot()); 
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent--

Comment: @steffen just an oversight, done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
Path p = Path.of("E:\\AllMusic\\The Shadows\\The Very Best of The Shadows");
do {
    System.out.println(p);
} while ((p = p.getParent()) != null);
```

Output:

```
E:\AllMusic\The Shadows\The Very Best of The Shadows
E:\AllMusic\The Shadows
E:\AllMusic
E:\
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the methods `getNameCount()` and `getName(int index)` of `java.nio.Path`

```
File f = new File("E:\AllMusic\The Shadows\The Very Best of The Shadows");
Path p = f.toPath();
int pathElements = p.getNameCount();

for (int i = 0; i < pathElements; ++i) {
    Path subPath = p.subpath(0, pathElements - i - 1);
}
```

Comment: hi i updated the code, I had misread the question please reconsider

Comment: You mix File (java.io) and Path (java.nio) which is possible but sometimes confusing. It is not necessary here, see answer of @steffen. While your answer is not incorrect, using io xor nio is cleaner :-)